# Convert code to a function with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-defined-functions

I have following code to plot barchart on a world map. What i want to implement is to make it plot based on user input. For example there should be a check box saying the chart can be plotted or not. If plot checkbox is checked it should plot the graph and if not it should not plot the graph. Can this be implemented in the javascript function itself. IF so please provide some insights on this. The code is as below:

```
// *** GLOBAL VARIABLES *******************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

// Main scene vars
var camera, scene, renderer, projector, spotLight;
var mouse = { }, touch = { },  INTERSECTED, intersectedId;
var camPos = { x:100, y:100, z:1800 };
var browserRender;

// The deviation position of the ground from the center
var yDeviation, zDeviation, xDeviation;

// Creates the value scale variables
var niceScale;

// bars array
var bars, intersobj;

// scale texts arrays
var sTextVals, sTextRows, sTextCols;


// *** VARIABLES INITIALIZATION ***********************************************
// ****************************************************************************

function initSceneVars(){

  // mouse/touch position
  //-3000 to make ot out of the screen
  mouse.x = -3000;
  mouse.y = -3000;
  touch.x = -3000;
  touch.y = -3000;
  touch.device = false;
  INTERSECTED = null;
  intersectedId = null;

  // Inits deviation position of the ground from the center
  yDeviation = -(valHeight/2);
  zDeviation = -(schema.cols.length*squareStep/2);
  xDeviation = -(schema.rows.length*squareStep/2);

  // Inits the value scale variables
  niceScale = new NiceScale ( getMinArr ( dataValues ), 
                              getMaxArr ( dataValues ) );
  niceScale.calculate ();

  // bars array
  bars = [];
  intersobj = [];

  // scale texts arrays
  sTextVals = [];
  sTextRows = [];
  sTextCols = [];

  // changes background colour
  $('body').css('background-color', '#'+backColor);

  // removes previous canvas if exists
  $('canvas').remove();

  // Getting the projector for picking objects
  projector = new THREE.Projector();

  // Creating new scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Setting the camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60,
                                        window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
                                        1,
                                        5000 );
  camera.position.set(camPos.x,camPos.y,camPos.z);

  // Extending the BarCube class with longitude and latitude of the bars
  BarCube.prototype.dummyLng = null;
  BarCube.prototype.dummyLat = null;
}


// *** SCENE INITIALIZATION FOR WEBGL RENDERER ********************************
// ****************************************************************************

function initWebGLScene () {

  // Setting the renderer (with shadows)
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  // Switch off the shadows for safari due to the three.js bug with it
  if( !$.browser.safari && $.browser.version != "534.57.2"){
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
  }

  $('body').append( renderer.domElement );

  //*** Adding the supernove background *****
  // ****************************************

  // Create particle for glow
  var particles = new THREE.Geometry();
  particles.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)));
  gpMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xFFFFFF,
          size: 3800,
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
              "static/img/world_glow.png"
          ),
          blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
      });
  var particleGlow = new THREE.ParticleSystem(particles,
                                              gpMaterial);
  particleGlow.sortParticles = true;
  scene.add(particleGlow);


  //*** Adding the globe ********
  //******************************

  // setting up the defuse map
  var matDif = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "static/img/world_diffuse.jpg");

  // setting up the bump map
  var mapBump = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "static/img/world_bump.jpg" );
  mapBump.anisotropy = 1;
  mapBump.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
  mapBump.offset.set( 0, 0 )
  mapBump.wrapS = mapBump.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  mapBump.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

  // setting up the material
  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    ambient : 0x444444,
    color : 0x777777,
    shininess : 40, 
    specular : 0x222222,
    shading : THREE.SmoothShading,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map:matDif,
    bumpMap:mapBump,
    bumpScale: 10
  });
  // creaing the mesh
  var globe = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry( globeRadius,
                                                        32,
                                                        32),
                              sphereMaterial);
  globe.receiveShadow = true;
  // add the globe to the scene
  scene.add(globe); 

  //*** Creating the bars and attaching them to the globe ********
  //**************************************************************

  for ( var i=0; i<schema.cols.length; i++ ) {
    if( dataValues[i][0] > 0 ) {
      // crating the bar object
      var color="E28105";
      bars.push( new BarCube( schema.cols[i].color, 0, i,
                          dataValues[i][0], valTextColor,
                          'full', $('#valuelabel'),
                          { row:schema.rows[0].name,
                            col:schema.cols[i].name },
                            niceScale.niceMin,
                            niceScale.range,
                            valHeight ) );
      // removeing the 3d label
      bars[bars.length-1].hasLabel = true;
      // making the widht of the bar smaller
      bars[bars.length-1].sqsize = 10;
      // getting the country from the country list
      var c = country[schema.cols[i].name];
      // add dummy object along wich we can rotate the bar for the longitute
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng = new THREE.Mesh( 
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 0, 0 ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xCCCCCC }));
      globe.add(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng);

      // add dummy object along wich we can rotate the bar for the latitude
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat = new THREE.Mesh( 
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 0, 0 ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xCCCCCC }));
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng.add(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat);
      // adding the bar to the scene and positioning it to the earth surface
      bars[bars.length-1].addBar(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat);
      bars[bars.length-1].reposition(0,globeRadius+bars[bars.length-1].h/2,0);
      // rotating the dummy object so that it snaps to the correct country
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng.rotation.y = Math.PI + (c.lng).toRad();
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat.rotation.x = Math.PI/2 - (c.lat).toRad();
      // adding the bar to the intersection objects
      intersobj[bars.length-1] = bars[bars.length-1].barobj;
      intersobj[bars.length-1].barid = bars.length-1;
    }
  }

  // focus the globe on a certain country
  var cfoc = country[countryFocus];
  globe.rotation.set(cfoc.lat.toRad(), Math.PI - cfoc.lng.toRad(), 0);

  //*** Adding the lights
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x999999 );
  light.position.set( -1, 0, 1 ).normalize();
  scene.add( light );

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x999999 );
  light.position.set( 0, 1, -1 ).normalize();
  scene.add( light );

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x999999 );
  light.position.set( 1, 0, -1 ).normalize();
  scene.add( light );

  spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF, 2 );
  spotLight.position.set( camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z );
  spotLight.target.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

  spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 1;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 3000;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 100;
  spotLight.castShadow = true;
  spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
  spotLight.shadowBias = 0.001;
  // spotLight.shadowCameraVisible  = true;
  scene.add( spotLight );
  ////////////////////

}


// *** SCENE INITIALIZATION FOR CANVAS RENDERER *******************************
// ****************************************************************************

function initCanvasScene () {
  // Setting the Canavas renderer
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer( );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  $('body').append( renderer.domElement );

  //*** Adding the grounds


  var mapText = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(staticUrl+"img/world_mapplain2.jpg");

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: mapText, overdraw: true } );

  // MAP SOLUTION

  // var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 3000, 1500, 6, 3 );                      
  // var globe = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  // scene.add( globe );
  // globe.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;

  // for ( var i=0; i<schema.cols.length; i++ ) {
  //   if( dataValues[i][0] > 0 ) {
  //     // crating the bar object
  //     bars.push( new BarCube( schema.cols[i].color, 0, i,
  //                         dataValues[i][0], valTextColor,
  //                         'light', $('#valuelabel'),
  //                         { row:schema.rows[0].name,
  //                           col:schema.cols[i].name },
  //                           niceScale.niceMin,
  //                           niceScale.range,
  //                           valHeight ) );
  //     // removeing the 3d label
  //     bars[bars.length-1].hasLabel = false;
  //     // making the widht of the bar smaller
  //     bars[bars.length-1].sqsize = 10;
  //     // getting the country from the country list
  //     var c = country[schema.cols[i].name];
  //     // adding the bar to the scene and positioning it to the earth surface
  //     bars[bars.length-1].addBar(globe);
  //     bars[bars.length-1].reposition(i*10,0,bars[bars.length-1].h/2);
  //     bars[bars.length-1].reorientation(Math.PI/2,0,0);
  //     // rotating the dummy object so that it snaps to the correct country
  //     // adding the bar to the intersection objects
  //     intersobj[bars.length-1] = bars[bars.length-1].barobj;
  //     intersobj[bars.length-1].barid = bars.length-1;
  //   }
  // }


  // GLOBE SOLUTION
  var globe = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry( globeRadius,
                                                        16,
                                                        16),
                              material);
  scene.add( globe );


  for ( var i=0; i<schema.cols.length; i++ ) {
    if( dataValues[i][0] > 0 ) {
      // crating the bar object
      bars.push( new BarCube( schema.cols[i].color, 0, i,
                          dataValues[i][0], valTextColor,
                          'light', $('#valuelabel'),
                          { row:schema.rows[0].name,
                            col:schema.cols[i].name },
                            niceScale.niceMin,
                            niceScale.range,
                            valHeight ) );
      // removeing the 3d label
      bars[bars.length-1].hasLabel = false;
      // making the widht of the bar smaller
      bars[bars.length-1].sqsize = 10;
      // getting the country from the country list
      var c = country[schema.cols[i].name];
      // add dummy object along wich we can rotate the bar for the longitute
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng = new THREE.Mesh( 
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 0, 0 ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xCCCCCC }));
      globe.add(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng);
      // add dummy object along wich we can rotate the bar for the latitude
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat = new THREE.Mesh( 
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 0, 0 ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xCCCCCC }));
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng.add(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat);
      // adding the bar to the scene and positioning it to the earth surface
      bars[bars.length-1].addBar(bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat);
      bars[bars.length-1].reposition(0,globeRadius+bars[bars.length-1].h/2,0);
      // rotating the dummy object so that it snaps to the correct country
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLng.rotation.y = Math.PI + (c.lng).toRad();
      bars[bars.length-1].dummyLat.rotation.x = Math.PI/2 - (c.lat).toRad();
      // adding the bar to the intersection objects
      intersobj[bars.length-1] = bars[bars.length-1].barobj;
      intersobj[bars.length-1].barid = bars.length-1;
    }
  }

  var cfoc = country[countryFocus];
  globe.rotation.set(cfoc.lat.toRad(), Math.PI - cfoc.lng.toRad(), 0);

  //*** Adding the lights ********
  //******************************
  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
  scene.add( ambientLight );

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
  directionalLight.position.x = 0.4;
  directionalLight.position.y = 0.4;
  directionalLight.position.z = - 0.2;
  directionalLight.position.normalize();
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
  directionalLight.position.x = - 0.2;
  directionalLight.position.y = 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.z = - 0.1;
  directionalLight.position.normalize();
  scene.add( directionalLight );
  //******************************

}


// *** SCENE INITIALIZATION ***************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

function initScene() {

  // Detecting the renderer:
  browserRender = detectRenderer ( );

  // Setting the renderer to null in case an old version of FF or IE
  if(($.browser.msie&&parseFloat($.browser.version)<9)||
     ($.browser.mozilla&&parseFloat($.browser.version)<2)){
    browserRender = null;
  }

  // Init vars and scene depending on the renderer
  if ( browserRender == 'webgl' ) {
    initSceneVars ();
    initWebGLScene ();
  }
  else if ( browserRender == 'canvas' ) {
    initSceneVars ();
    initCanvasScene ();
  }
  else {
    nonSupportedBrowsers();
  }

  controls = mouseControls ( camera , 1200, 2800 );

}


// *** SCENE ANIMATION ********************************************************
// ****************************************************************************

function animateScene() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animateScene );

  // Updateing the controls for the trackball camera
  controls.update();

  // find intersections - from the Mr.Doob example
  // url: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html

  // Checks first if it's touch or mouse device
  if (!touch.device) {
    var actCoord = { x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y };
  }else{
    var actCoord = { x: touch.x, y: touch.y };
  }

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3( actCoord.x, actCoord.y, 1 );

  projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

  var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, 
                            vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( intersobj );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
      if ( INTERSECTED ) {
        INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
        bars[intersectedId].hideLabel();
      }
      INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
      INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
      INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 
              parseInt( bars[intersects[0].object.barid].darklumcolor, 16 ) );
      bars[intersects[0].object.barid].showLabel( actCoord.x, actCoord.y );
      intersectedId = intersects[0].object.barid;
    }
  } else {
    if ( INTERSECTED ) {
      INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
      bars[intersectedId].hideLabel();
    }
    intersectedId = null;
    INTERSECTED = null;
  }

  if ( browserRender=='webgl' ) {
    // set the spotlight to move with the camera
    spotLight.position.set( camera.position.x, 
                            camera.position.y-200, 
                            camera.position.z+200);
  }

  // renders                        
  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

// Converts numeric degrees to radians
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}
```

Creating bars and attaching them to globe is the part which i want to be executed based on user input. Problem is it should work with the flow. Can some one tell me how i can implement a conditional part over there. It would be alot helpful if some one can guide me on this problem.

Comment: small free advice, its always good to shorten/brief/make-to-the-point the code in Question..

Comment: yea..sorry about that. But i wanted to show that this whole thing is required. The part i mention wont work if i make it into a function and call it separately because it needs to work according to the flow.